# Labeling from a defined string in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, labeling, mapbasic

I am currently working on a code to apply a variety of different changes to layers with certain attributes, I have been successful with this so far (thanks to Peter). However I now want to add a text box to this so the user can enter the name of the field they want labeling (as this is the only thing differs in the .TABs I intend to use this tool for).

I have currently created a dialog box for the user to input this however when it comes to labeling (I assume), MapInfo is looking for a field with the same name as my string to label with, instead of looking at what is stored there.

For example

```
Dim sLabinput As String


Set Map Window nMID
            Layer nLayer 
                Display Global Global Line (2,2,16711680)
                Arrows On
                    Label With sLabinput Auto On Visibility On
                    Font ("Arial",257,9,0,16777215)
```

I haven't put the rest of the code as I want to try and learn this myself however if that is the only way to solve it I can post it.

Am I right in assuming in this instance MapInfo is looking for a field called sLabinput, rather than the value stored in there?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Managed to play around with the code and an answer from somewhere else. I'm going to post it in case

```
Include "MAPBASIC.DEF"

Dim sLabinput As String

Dialog
    Title "Section Ref"
    Control statictext
        Title "Enter section ref field"
    Control edittext
        Value sLabinput
        into sLabinput
    Control OKButton
    Control CancelButton

if commandinfo (CMD_INFO_DLG_OK) then

Else
End Program
End if

Dim nMID, nLayer As Integer, sLayer As String

nMID = FrontWindow()
For nLayer = 1 To MapperInfo(nMID, MAPPER_INFO_LAYERS)
    sLayer = LayerInfo(nMID, nLayer, LAYER_INFO_NAME)
    If sLayer Like "%AllG%" Then
        Set Map Window nMID
            Layer nLayer 
                Display Global Global Line (1,2,45056)   
    ElseIf sLayer Like "%roup0%" Then
        Run Command "Set Map Window " & nMID & " Layer " &nLayer
            & " Label With " & sLabinput
            Set Map Window nMID
            Layer nLayer 
                Display Global Global Line (2,2,16711680)
                Arrows On
                  Label Auto ON Font ("Arial",257,9,0,16777215)




    '**add extra cases here below if you need to
    '**ElseIf sLayer Like "%zz%" Then
    '**    Set Map Window nMID
    '**        Layer nLayer 
    '**            Display Global Global Line (2,2,16711680)
    '**            Arrows On
    End if
Next
```

Comment: Good to see my suggestion worked, Alan. Another way might be to use an Alias variable to hold a combination of the table and column name:

Answer (score 0):

Good to see my suggestion worked, Alan.

Another way might be to use an Alias variable to hold a combination of the table and column name:

```
Dim aLabel as Alias
Dim nMID, nLayer As Integer, sLayer As String

nMID = FrontWindow()
For nLayer = 1 To MapperInfo(nMID, MAPPER_INFO_LAYERS)
    sLayer = LayerInfo(nMID, nLayer, LAYER_INFO_NAME)
    If sLayer Like "%AllG%" Then
        Set Map Window nMID
            Layer nLayer 
                Display Global Global Line (1,2,45056)   
    ElseIf sLayer Like "%roup0%" Then
        aLabel = sLayer & "." & sLabinput
        Set Map Window nMID
           Layer nLayer
             Label With aLabel
        Set Map Window nMID
           Layer nLayer 
              Display Global Global Line (2,2,16711680)
              Arrows On
              Label Auto ON Font ("Arial",257,9,0,16777215)

    '**add extra cases here below if you need to
    '**ElseIf sLayer Like "%zz%" Then
    '**    Set Map Window nMID
    '**        Layer nLayer 
    '**            Display Global Global Line (2,2,16711680)
    '**            Arrows On
    End if
Next
```

If it works, you can use a single Set Map statement instead of two separate statements - not that that will make a big difference